# Connect the tenant's Azure AD from my partner center account/Delegated account getting Error

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, connection

While connecting the tenant's Azure AD from my partner center account/Delegated account, I'm getting below error.

Connect-AzureAD: One or more errors occurred.: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration 
change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must 
use multi-factor authentication to access 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'.

I'm doing some automation task but this error unable to make me connect to tenant's Azure AD:

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred -TenantId $id

$cred: Credential of my DA account
$id: tenant's ID to which I have to connect.

Please help..........

Comment: Hi, SO is a platform to assist with coding issues. This looks like a configuration issue instead of a coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using interactive authentication, it'll allow you to go through MFA:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $id
```

Sounds like you are trying to pass username and password and by extension, using the ROPC flow.
It won't work if MFA is required.
You need to go through interactive authentication.